# How to do an Upsert using Mongo spark connector in Java?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

How to do an Upsert using Mongo spark connector in Java? `MongoSpark` class doesn't seem to provide methods to specify filters and so on.

I have a Dataset that represent json documents and I want to do something like this using Mongo-Spark-Java connector

`collection.replaceOne(
    and(
        eq("_id", "1234"), lt("TIMESTAMP",document.getString("TIMESTAMP")
    ), 
       document, 
                new UpdateOptions().upsert(true)
 )`

Looking for some example code on how to do this using Mongo-Spark-Java connector.